# Why does "onCreate" keep getting called from the launcher?

Tags: android, shortcut, android-launcher

### Background

I've called a simple code to create a shortcut to an activity. The code is very similar to this one:

```
Intent shortcutintent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.shortcutname));
Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.icon);
shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MainActivity.class));
sendBroadcast(shortcutintent);
```

### The problem

Thing is, when I open the app, then press the home button, and then click on the app's icon on the launcher, I can see that onCreate is being called again (I've put a toast in onCreate).

### What I've tried

I've tried various intent flags to fix this, but couldn't find one.

### The question

It happened not just on third parth lanchers (Nova Launcher in my case), but also on official stock version of Android 6, on Nexus 5.

How could this be? Why does the launcher re-open the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your activity as singleTop on your manifest:

```
 <activity...
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        ...>
    </activity>
```

Adding the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP to the intent should work as well:

```
....new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Comment: The other app that I create a shortcut to isn't of mine. What I wrote is an example. However, when adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP to the intent that I pass on EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT , it works. Please update your answer and I will tick it.

Comment: I've noticed you've edited the answer. Do note that when you do it, it doesn't notify me. Anyway, I'll tick your answer now. Can you please explain how come I can't see this flag being used in the code of the play store, though? Yet their intent doesn't seem to create a new instance of the apps each time...